# ClassNotFoundException when receiving AMQP messages after upgrade to Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR3

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

After upgrading Spring Cloud from Hoxton.SR1 to Hoxton.SR3 our application throws the following exception every time a message is received even though the message is still being processed as expected:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.domain.message.DiagramDeletedMessage
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders.getClassForValue(JsonHeaders.java:89)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders.buildResolvableType(JsonHeaders.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.createJsonResolvableTypHeaderInAny(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.extractStandardHeaders(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:155)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.extractStandardHeaders(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper.toHeaders(AbstractHeaderMapper.java:266)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(AbstractHeaderMapper.java:203)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:337)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.java:61)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:281)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1579)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer$$Lambda$1393/1038281434.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1284)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.domain.message.DiagramDeletedMessage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:144)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders.getClassForValue(JsonHeaders.java:86)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

It seems like this behaviour is due to changes performed in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/2f4394d8b527b227d0ee2ff43de0ec2a50ffefef. Now the `json__TypeId__` header containing the FQN of the message is used to try and resolve the message type.

Since the exception is logged as warning we have set set the log level for Spring's `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` to `ERROR` for now. However this can also hide other possibly important warnings.

I'm wondering if this is an issue with the aforementioned change to spring-integration and what the best way would be to avoid having our logs filled with stacktraces.

Comment: Sorry, wrong issue

Comment: Why does your `_TypeId__` header haver such a weird value `source.package.message` ? How do you deserialize your JSON if that header doesn't look like a class name?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to display the company's name so I anonymized the package name but went a little overboard. I changed it back to something more readable in my initial post.

Comment: As for the second question. We assumed that the deserialization is performed by a field by field comparison of the serialized object and the type of the `@Payload` annotated parameter in the `@StreamListener` method.